# R time format conversion

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I have almost finished my script but I have a problem with my dates format.
I installed lubridate package used the as_date function, but it doesn't give me what I want (a date).
"time" is my variable, I put its description below.

I do not put my entire script since the concern is only about this format question (and it implies a huge netcdf file impossible to download)

Could you help me please ?

```
class(time)
[1] "array"

head(time)
[1] 3573763200 3573774000 3573784800 3573795600 3573806400 3573817200

tunits
$long_name
[1] "time in seconds (UT)"
$standard_name
[1] "time"
$units
[1] "seconds since 1900-01-01T00:00:00Z"
$axis
[1] "T"
$time_origin
[1] "01-JAN-1900 00:00:00"
$conventions
[1] "relative number of seconds with no decimal part"

#conversion
date = as_date(time,tz="UTC",origin = "1900-01-01")
head(date)
[1] "-5877641-06-23" "-5877641-06-23" "-5877641-06-23" "-5877641-06-23"
[5] "-5877641-06-23" "-5877641-06-23"
```

Comment: Try `as.POSIXct` instead of `as_date`.

Comment: @AllanCameron thank you, I came to the same conclusion (and it works).
I have a new problem now, when I want to construct a table with my date in the new format and another variable (numeric class, temperature), the column which contains the dates returns to the previous format, why?

Comment: Difficult to say without a reproducible example Celine, but the easiest thing might be to convert to date with `date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(time, origin = "1900-01-01"))`. If you are working with a data frame, ensure you specify that you are writing to a column called date in the dataframe (i.e. `df$date <- as.Date(as.POSIXct(time, origin = "1900-01-01"))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time is in seconds since 01/01/1900. Converting a value in `time` to an actual date would work as follows, using the `seconds` methods in `lubridate`:

```
lubridate::ymd("1900-01-01") + lubridate::seconds(3573763200)
```

You can vectorize it:

```
lubridate::ymd("1900-01-01") + lubridate::seconds(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

`as_date()` calculates the date using the number of days since the origin.

What you are looking for seems to be `as_datetime()` also from the `lubridate` package which calculates the date using the number of seconds since the origin. In your example this would be:

```
time <- c(3573763200,3573774000,3573784800,3573795600,3573806400,3573817200)
date <- as_datetime(time, tz = "UTC", origin = "1900-01-01") %>% date()
```

Using a `dplyr` pipe and the `date()` function from `lubridate` to extract the date from the `as_datetime()` function.

Answer (score 0):

```r
date <- as_date(time/(24*60*60), tz = "UTC", origin = "1900-01-01")  
date
```